# Weird ptp-bin directory

Tags: linux, perl

In my home directory the `ptp-bin/` appeared.

It contains one file `ptp` with the following content:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
require("File/Spec.pm");my@files=();my$aflag=0;my$type=undef;for$a(@ARGV){if(${a}eq"-a"){$aflag=1;}elsif($a=~/-t=(.*)/){$type=$1;}elsif(-r$a){push@files,File::Spec->rel2abs($a);}}if($#files==0){if(defined($type)){print"~~EPTP:OpenFile~~EDID=",$type,"~~",$files[0],"\n";}else{print"~~EPTP:OpenFile~~",$files[0],"\n";}}elsif($aflag){for$file(@files){if(defined($type)){print"~~EPTP:OpenFile~~EDID=",$type,"~~",$file,"\n";}else{print"~~EPTP:OpenFile~~",$file,"\n";}sleep(1);}}else{if(defined($type)){print"~~EPTP:Choice~~EDID=",$type,"~~",join("~~",@files),"\n";}else{print"~~EPTP:Choice~~",join("~~",@files),"\n";}}
```

Is it okay and what should I do with it?
What does it do?
Should I delete it or move somewhere?

Comment: Were you downloading or installing anything around the time that the file was created? (check the timestamp of the file for a hint). Do you need the program for anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ptp` script is a Perl script used for opening a file in the Eclipse editor.

The script is reproduced and explained in the documentation for something called the Parallel Tools Platform (PTP).  See e.g. the [Terminal View](https://wiki.eclipse.org/PTP/new_and_noteworthy/8.0.0#Terminal_View) section:

> It is possible for the shell and the terminal to interact, allowing the eclipse user to have the best of both the command line and the GUI.
>
> For example, a short command can call up the Eclipse editor from the command line [...screenshot etc. not reproduced here...]
>
> It is convenient to invoke the above escape sequences through the use of scripts. The following script is suggested for opening files on the remote machine. An example follows:

(the script that you mention is then given).

> Using this script, it is possible to open any file within the Eclipse editor by typing:
>
> ```
> ptp filename
> ```
>
> Note that the file name can be relative or absolute.

I'll leave it up to you to decide what to do with this script.